# `?` causing segmentation fault in Xcode 8.3.2's Swift compiler

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this line of Swift which use to compile without issue

```
let layoutSettings = try LayoutSettings.deserialize(params: layoutSettingsParams as Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>)
```

As of Xcode 8.3.2 I get the error

> Swift Compiler Error
>     Command failed due to signal:
>     Segmentation fault: 11

If I remove the `?` at the end of the line of code it compiles without issue.

How do I use the nullable type without crashing the compiler?

Comment: try using as? instead of as

Comment: So... what is the runtime type of `layoutSettingsParams` _before_ you cast it?

Comment: A dictionary with optional values is counterproductive in Swift anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**AnyObject** and **AnyObject?** are not the same thing. **AnyObject?** is actually syntactic sugar for **Optional< AnyObject >**.   The fact that it compiles with **Dictionary< String, AnyObject >** but not **Dictionary< String, AnyObject? >** means that **Dictionary< String, AnyObject >** or [String: AnyObject] is the correct type, or convertible to the correct type.  In general the swift compiler occasionally has problems with type inference which either causes it to crash or to compile very slowly.  I notice this most frequently with dictionaries and with returns from .map().  In both cases if you explicitly state the type (even if according to the rules of the language it should be inferred) it usually helps the compiler go faster and/or not crash.  In these instances I think it also helps the reader, because if the compiler can't infer the type easily its often the case that a human can't do it without some thinking as well.

Comment: Well said. See also https://medium.com/swift-programming/speeding-up-slow-swift-build-times-922feeba5780